# ORMDroid - NullPointerException

Tags: android, sqlite, orm

I'm trying to use ORMDroid to make a very basic table of users. I can't work out why it's giving me this NullPointerException. The code that generates the error is:

```
@Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

             Context context = getApplicationContext();
             String newname = fullName.getText().toString();
             String newage = age.getText().toString();
             String newuser = userName.getText().toString();
             String newpassword = password.getText().toString();
             String newgender = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); 

             try {
                Log.d(null, "Start");
                 Person p = Entity.query(Person.class).where("id=1").execute();
                 Log.d(null, "Name: " + newname);
                 Log.d(null, "two");
                 p.name = newname;
                 Log.d(null, "three");
                 p.age = newage;
                 p.username = newuser;
                 p.password = newpassword;
                 p.gender = newgender;
                 Log.d(null, "four");
                 p.save();
                 Log.d(null, "five");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error saving your information", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

             Toast.makeText(context, "" + newname + newpassword + newuser + newage + newgender, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }

     });
```

The person class is:

```
package com.ucs.thehealthyapp;

import com.roscopeco.ormdroid.Entity;
import com.roscopeco.ormdroid.Table;

@Table(name="users")
public class Person extends Entity {

  public int id;

  public String name;

  public String age;

  public String username;

  public String password;

  public String gender;

}
```

And then the error is throws up is:

```
02-25 15:37:56.809: D/(13945): Start
02-25 15:37:56.809: V/Query(13945): SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=1 LIMIT 1
02-25 15:37:56.809: D/(13945): Name: Tom
02-25 15:37:56.809: D/(13945): two
02-25 15:37:56.809: W/System.err(13945): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 15:37:56.809: W/System.err(13945):    at com.ucs.thehealthyapp.Register$1.onClick(Register.java:73)
02-25 15:37:56.809: W/System.err(13945):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4340)
02-25 15:37:56.809: W/System.err(13945):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17634)
02-25 15:37:56.809: W/System.err(13945):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-25 15:37:56.809: W/System.err(13945):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-25 15:37:56.809: W/System.err(13945):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-25 15:37:56.809: W/System.err(13945):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5171)
02-25 15:37:56.809: W/System.err(13945):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 15:37:56.809: W/System.err(13945):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-25 15:37:56.809: W/System.err(13945):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
02-25 15:37:56.809: W/System.err(13945):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
02-25 15:37:56.809: W/System.err(13945):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I just don't understand where I am going wrong. This is also my first foray into building apps so that might explain it...I bet it's something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
  p.name = newname;
```

your `p == null` => NPE

Looks like your query does return null here:

```
  Person p = Entity.query(Person.class).where("id=1").execute();
```

check if p == null before using it

Comment: Right OK, this makes sense. I'd assumed this line was opening the table, although I didn't really understand it. So since I was trying to create entries with this query command it was failing. There is actually a command for creating entires: `Person p = new Person();`